# File transfer over java sockets using multiple IO streams

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, file-transfer, large-files

Recently, I wrote a simple client server program for file transfer over standard TCP sockets. The average throughput was around 2.2Mbps over WiFi channel. My question is:
Is it possible to transfer a large file (say 5 GB) over multiple data IO streams so that each stream could transfer several parts of the same file in a parallel manner (different threads could be used for this purpose)? These file parts could be re-assembled at the receiving end.
I tried to split a small file and transfered it over a dataoutputstream. The first segment works fine, but I don't know how to read a file input stream in selective manner (I also tried mark() and reset() methods for selective reading but no use)

Here is my code (for testing purpose, I have redirected the output to fileoutputstream):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final File myFile=new File("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/testPicture.jpg");
    long N=myFile.length();
    try {
        FileInputStream in=new FileInputStream(myFile);
        FileOutputStream f0=new FileOutputStream("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/File1.jpg");
        FileOutputStream f1=new FileOutputStream("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/File2.jpg");
        FileOutputStream f2=new FileOutputStream("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/File3.jpg");

        byte[] buffer=new byte[4096];
        int i=1, noofbytes;
        long acc=0;
        while(acc<=(N/3)) {
            noofbytes=in.read(buffer, 0, 4096);
            f0.write(buffer, 0, noofbytes);
            acc=i*noofbytes;
            i++;
        }
        f0.close();
```

I got the first segment of my file (this can be copied to a DataOutputStream in one thread). Can any one suggest, how to read remaining part of the file (after N/3 byte) in a segment of N/3 so that three streams could be used in three threads for concurrent operation?

Here is the code to merge file segments at receiver end:

```
    package com.mergefilespackage;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MergeFiles {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        IOCopier.joinFiles(new File("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/File1.jpg"), new File[] {
            new File("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/File2.jpg"), new File("/home/evinish/Documents/Android/File3.jpg")});
    }
}
class IOCopier {
    public static void joinFiles(File destination, File[] sources)
            throws IOException {
        OutputStream output = null;
        try {
            output = createAppendableStream(destination);
            for (File source : sources) {
                appendFile(output, source);
            }
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(output);
        }
    }

    private static BufferedOutputStream createAppendableStream(File destination)
            throws FileNotFoundException {
        return new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destination, true));
    }

    private static void appendFile(OutputStream output, File source)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream input = null;
        try {
            input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
            IOUtils.copy(input, output);
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(input);
        }
    }
}
class IOUtils {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 4;

    public static long copy(InputStream input, OutputStream output)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        long count = 0;
        int n = 0;
        while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, n);
            count += n;
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void closeQuietly(Closeable output) {
        try {
            if (output != null) {
                output.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're trying to pump more data over the same WiFi channel it will likely become slower as each socket will increase contention for the others.

Comment: +1 to @hexafraction.  The question is what is the limiting factor.  I suspect (like @hex) that you are being bounded by the wifi speeds and since the other connections will be on the same wifi channel, they won't be able to work in parallel.

Comment: @Gray Posted as an answer.

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.. I'm new to socket programming, so just thought of exploring. Thanks for your valuable information btw! Can you suggest some of the optimization techniques for file transfer over java sockets? Is it okay to use dataoutputstream instead of file channels?

Comment: @VinitShandilya Your limitations will still be on the link(assuming you use `BufferedWriters`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get any more speed over the same link with more sockets. Each socket sends a certain number of packets, each of a certain size. As we double the number of sockets, the number of packets/sec*socket is halved, and then decreased *even more* due to collisions, overhead, and contention. Packets start to bump, jumble, and otherwise panic. The OS cannot handle the pandemonium of lost ACKs, and the WiFi card struggles to transmit at such a rate. It is losing its low-level acks as well. As packets get lost, a desperate TCP stack dials down the transmit rate. If this were to be able to come up due to signal improvement, it's now stuck at the lower speed due to silly window syndrome or another form of TCP deadlock.

Any attempt of WiFi to get any higher speeds out of wider carrier bands, MiMo, or multiple paths, has already been realized as gains, even with one socket. You can't take it any farther.

Now, wait. We're quite below WiFi speed, aren't we? Of course, we need to use buffering!

Make sure you create BufferedWriter and BufferedReader objects from your socket's getInputStream or getOutputStream methods. Then write to/read from those buffers. Your speed may increase somewhat.

Comment: +1 The throughput per socket is halved because of the limits of the WIFI channel throughput.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the byte array of the `FileInputStream` and split it every 10 KB (every 10.000 bytes).
Then send these parts through the streams in order.

On the server you can put the arrays together again and read the file from this giant byte array.

Comment: 10KB **!=** 10000bytes

Comment: This won't result in higher throughput, just more complex code.

Comment: Well... Then split it every 10240 bytes

Comment: @BackSlash 10KB=10000 bytes. 10KiB=10240 bytes. The number is valid though there still won't be higher throughput.